# CKEditor Alternative for my site

Tags: wysiwyg

My question sounds silly, but I'm currently using CKEditor on one of my projects that I work on, I'm looking for a good alternative sinceCK is giving me issues "long story". I'm looking for a similar product that's free together with a free image uploader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/). I'm not sure however if there is a suitable [provider](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/127/postid/244932/scope/posts/Default.aspx) available.

Comment: TinyMCE hasn't builtin image upload! you should buy a plugin for image upload.

Answer (score 4):

Another WYSIWYG editor that I really like is http://editor.froala.com. It has a lot of formatting options, image upload and image resize that works even on mobile devices.

Comment: Do you work for Froala? Your only answers (and you've posted no questions) say "look at Froala, it's good!" You must have searched them out as they are very old. But it made me look and it looks very interesting!